# Как складывать осуществлять математические операции с числами с плавающей запятой?

Tags: javascript

Как осуществлять математические операции с плавающими запятыми?

Пример:
(1.7976931348623157e+308 + 1.7976931348623157e+308) / 2 = 1.7976931348623157e+308

Comment: `console.log(1.2 + 1 + 1.2);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Математические операции можно осуществлять с учетом возможного переполнения.

1.

```js
var a = 1.7976931348623157e+308;
var b = 1.7976931348623157e+308;
var c = (a + b) / 2;
console.log(a, b, c);
```

2.

```js
var a = 1.7976931348623157e+308;
var b = 1.7976931348623157e+308;
var c = a / 2 + b / 2;
console.log(a, b, c);
```